AppAuth Android 14 issue Communication problems between AuthorizationManagementActivity and RedirectUriReceiverActivity
Version: 0.11.1
Integration: native Kotlin
Identity provider: Google
My Problem is only on Android 14 devices. API 34.
I have Activity A and B.
Activity B has it own taskAffinity, and im launching the AuthRequest from Activity B and finishing im getting No stored state - unable to handle response warn from AuthorizationManagementActivity.
and its not redirecting the activity B but opening it own Task instance.
I've attempted to use AuthorizationManagementActivity and RedirectUriReceiverActivity with the same custom taskAffinity. It was unsuccessful. (DID NOT WORK)
I was expecting the result to redirect to Activity B and not opening a new orphan Activity with custom app stuck on login

checking this thread https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android/issues/977 its fixed on new android builds. But NOT SAMSUNG Devices. Apparently Samsung are still using the buggy android 14 build

Ok the bug was Mainly in Android Beta, but samsung is still carrying this bug on there Android 14 devices.
the issue is reproduced on Android 14 beta 4.1 with AppAuth-Android 0.11.1.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/288400064?pli=1
it was fixed now.
I managed to find the source of this issue. it was in the Activity result.
So nothing wrong with the AppAuth Android library. Its all in the Samsung Android 14 build.
I mentioned the fix in this comment here  https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android/issues/977#issuecomment-2129326556
